# How to rotate a node perpendicular to another node after physics contact

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have created a sample code.

In it I have a player(`:SKSpriteNode`) that I should to position on Asteroid(:`SKSpriteNode`) , perpendicular it.

This is a wrong image. The player should stay by foot on the surface, not touching it by head ). The image I have taken from real project, where I create a "fake player" after contact.

[image]

Therefore I use `didBeginContact` method.

In contact method I am positioning a player on the asteroid - and it is gone. it disappeared.  **Why I don't see my player on the asteroid?**

**Second question, how to rotate a player perpendicular to the surface of the asteroid?**

Here is my didBeginContact Method:

```
  func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    
    if ((contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == EntityCategory.Player && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == EntityCategory.Asteroid) ||
        (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == EntityCategory.Player && contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == EntityCategory.Asteroid)) {
        
            if self.player.parent != self {
                return
            }
            
        let asterPoint =  asteroid.convertPoint(contact.contactPoint, fromNode: self)
        
        let playerNode = self.player
            
        playerNode.removeFromParent()
        playerNode.position = CGPointZero//asterPoint
        playerNode.zRotation = reflectionAngleFromContact(contact)
        playerNode.zPosition = self.asteroid.zPosition + 1
            
        self.asteroid.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask &= ~EntityCategory.Player
            
        self.asteroid.addChild(playerNode)
        
       
    }
}
```

It uses method `reflectionAngleFromContact(contact)`:

```
  func shortestAngleBetween(angle1: CGFloat,
    angle2: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let twoπ = π * 2.0
        var angle = (angle2 - angle1) % twoπ
        if (angle >= π) {
            angle = angle - twoπ
        }
        if (angle <= -π) {
            angle = angle + twoπ
        }
        return angle
}

func reflectionAngleFromContact(contact:SKPhysicsContact!) -> CGFloat {
    
    var normal = contact.contactNormal
    
    var point = contact.contactPoint
    
    var point2 = CGPointMake(point.x -  normal.dx*10, point.y -  normal.dy*10)
    
    let extraAngle = shortestAngleBetween(point.angle, angle2: point2.angle)
    
    return extraAngle
}


override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    
    let touch = (touches.first as! UITouch)
    let point = touch.locationInNode(self)
    
    self.player.flyToPoint(point)
   }
  }


extension CGPoint {

   var angle: CGFloat {
    return atan2(y, x)
  }
}
```

I also tried to rotate player using scalar multiplication of two vectors = |v1| * |v2| * cos

And used arcos after that, but it didn't work.

Forgot to place the link on the test project, please help ))

[Source code to test](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bylke6zx7bdphpm/AAC5a4vXrJLBr7VfdYCbieOaa?dl=0)

P.S. I have found why the player was not presented on the screen: I moved it by custom action, that is why I had to remove them after adding it to the scene.

```
player.removeAllActions()
```

I don't get why simple approach doesn't work :

```
func reflectionAngleFromContact3(contact:SKPhysicsContact!) -> CGFloat {

var normal = contact.contactNormal

println("Before reflection  Normal dx \(normal.dx),Normal dy \(normal.dy) . Angle (degree) \(normal.angle.degree)")

normal.dx *= CGFloat(-1.0)
normal.dy *= CGFloat(-1.0)

println("After reflection Normal dx \(normal.dx),Normal dy \(normal.dy) . Angle (degree) \(normal.angle.degree)")

var angle:CGFloat = normal.angle

return angle
```

}

How to position  the player properly, on the surface?